# Azure Devops Pipeline - Specify Target Framework with DotNetCoreCLI@2

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Is it possible to specify the target framework for a ClassLibrary project using Azure Devops Build Pipelines and the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task?  Or do we have to revert to using a script and manually calling the `dotnet publish` command?

A snippet from my pipeline YAML

```
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish' 
    publishWebProjects: false # Required when command == Publish
    projects: 'TestProject/Test/Test.csproj'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

And from my .csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.1;net45</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I'm using the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=vsts) for the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task but it's not always great.

**EDIT:** I should add that at the moment the Build completely fails because:

```
The 'Publish' target is not supported without specifying a target framework. 
The current project targets multiple frameworks, please specify the framework 
for the published application.
```

Comment: Hello @JLo ; a side question : Did you try to set buildConfiguration: 'Release' ? Because when I do this, the build is using 'Debug'

Answer (score 4):

The `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task could be extended with the `arguments` property, on which you could specify the framework (as well as the build configuration):

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish' 
    publishWebProjects: false # Required when command == Publish
    projects: 'TestProject/Test/Test.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --framework netcoreapp2.1'
```